# Angular app is not rendering properly on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm writing an store app with angular, but it's not renring properly on
the browser. I think i missed something but i can't see what:

I cutted the html file. It is just showing the first lines on which is writed
the link `<scripts>`.

I had fixed the punctuation signs by adding `<meta charset="utf-8">`. So by now the characters are showing poperly. I thing i forgot to add some other script from `angular aplication` but i can't see what!

[image: it should show titles and images, but it didn't]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="list-group" ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <header>
      <h1 class="text-center">Prueba tienda</h1>
      <h2 class="text-center">_ aplicación con Angular-js _</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat = "product in store.products">
      <h3>
        {{product.name}}
        <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
      </h3>
<!-- Image gallery -->
      <div class="gallery" ng-show="product.images.length"
           ng-controller="GalleryController as gallery">
        <img ng-src="{{product.images[gallery.current]}}">
        <ul class="list-inline thumbs">
          <li class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in product.images">
            <img ng-src="{{image}}" />
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <section class="tab" ng-controller="TabController as tabber">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{active: tabber.isSet(1)}">
          <a href ng-click="tabber.setTab(1)">Description</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: tabber.isSet(2)"}>
          <a href ng-click="tabber.setTab(2)">Specs</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: tabber.isSet(3)">
          <a href ng-click="tabber.setTab(3)">Reviews</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Review Tab's content -->
      <div ng-show="tabber.isSet(1)">


        <h4>Description</h4>
        <blockquote>{{product.description}}</blockquote>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="tabber.isSet(2)">
        <h4>Specs</h4>
        <blockquote>Shine: {{product.shine}}</blockquote>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="tabber.isSet(3)">

        <!-- Product Reviews List-->
        <ul>
          <h4>Reviews</h4>
          <li ng-repeat="review in product.reviews">
            <blockquote>
              <strong>{{review.stars}} Stars</strong>
              {{review.body}}
              <cite class"clearfix">-{{review.author}} on {{review.createdOn | date}}</cite>
            </blockquote>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <!--Review Form -->
            <form name="reviewForm"
                  ng-controller="ReviewController as reviewCtrl"
                  ng-submit="reviewForm.$valid && reviewCtrl.addReview(product)" novalidate>
              <!--  Live Preview -->
              <blockquote>
                <strong>{{reviewCtrl.review.stars}} Stars</strong>
                {{reviewCtrl.review.body}}
                <cite class="clearfix">—{{reviewCtrl.review.author}}</cite>
              </blockquote>

              <!--  Review Form -->
              <h4>Submit a Review</h4>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <select ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.stars" class="form-control" 
                        ng-options="stars for stars in [5,4,3,2,1]" 
                        title="Stars" required >
                  <option value="">Rate the Product</option>
                </select>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write a short review of the product..." 
                          title="Review" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.body"></textarea>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" type="email" class="form-control" 
                       placeholder="jimmyDean@example.org" title="Email" required/>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit Review" 
                       {{reviewForm..$valid}}/>
              </fieldset>
            </form>

      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore');

  app.controller('GalleryController', function() {
    this.current = 0;

    this.setCurrent = function(value) {
      this.current = value || 0;
    };
  });

  app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.products = gems;
  });

  app.controller('TabController', function() {
    this.tab = 1;

    this.setTab = function(selectTab) {
      this.tab = selectTab;
    };
    this.isSet = function(tabde) {
      return this.tab == tabde;
    };
  });

  app.controller('ReviewController', function() {
    this.review = {};

    this.addReview = function(product) {
      this.review.createOn = Date.now();
      product.reviews.push(this.review);
      this.review = {};
  };
});

  var gems = [{
    name: 'Azurite',
    description: "Some gems have hidden qualities beyond their luster, beyond their shine... Azurite is one of those gems.",
    shine: 8,
    price: 110.50,
    rarity: 7,
    color: '#CCC',
    faces: 14,
    images: [
      "images/gem-02.gif",
      "images/gem-05.gif",
      "images/gem-09.gif"
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Bloodstone',
    description: "Origin of the Bloodstone is unknown, hence its low value. It has a very high shine and 12 sides, however.",
    shine: 9,
    price: 22.90,
    rarity: 6,
    color: '#EEE',
    faces: 12,
    images: [
      "images/gem-01.gif",
      "images/gem-03.gif",
      "images/gem-04.gif"
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Zircon',
    description: "Zircon is our most coveted and sought after gem. You will pay much to be the proud owner of this gorgeous and high shine gem.",
    shine: 70,
    price: 1100,
    rarity: 2,
    color: '#000',
    faces: 6,
    images: [
      "images/gem-06.gif",
      "images/gem-07.gif",
      "images/gem-10.gif"
    ]
  }];
})();
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: i think yes... let me show it!

Comment: `When cancelling a request for http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d because the inner window was destroyed or a new favicon was loaded for it, it was already canceled!` and another one ...

Comment: I think you have forget some source file link for your dependency 'qrScanner', 'ngRoute'

Comment: Where are you defining the properties for products?

Comment: I was readeing something that speak about those modules, but i think that the app can run if i blow up those. This is the other error: `TypeError: asm.js type error: Disabled by 'asmjs' runtime option`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information, including a [mcve]. Read [ask] for more information about how to write a good question.

Comment: Now both files `index.html` and `app.js` are as they are. You can run a full test.

Comment: @hell0 change **var app = angular.module('gemStore');** to **var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);** and check whether app is loading or not

Comment: After a lot of changes, here in this post i can't say if that `[]` was missed first time, but in fact it solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: So if you write the response i will mark it as `accepted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `ngapp`

```
<html ng-app="gemStore">
```

and on your JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('gemstore', ['qrScanner', 'ngRoute']);
```

`gemstore` and `gemStore`, not matched,

look character `S`

make same in both places (case sensitive)

See [demo on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/bafinohelu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: fixed that. It is not rendering anyway. I tryed to remove angular.min.js, it doesn't worked. the `app.js`file is my app!

Comment: I think the problem was in that misstyped `s`. Thank you i'm accepting this response.

Answer (score 0):

Include only one Angular js file in script tag either min.js or simple js but it should before app.js.

Comment: He is?  I dont see how this answers the question.

Comment: Please check typo in var app = angular.module('gemstore', ['qrScanner', 'ngRoute']);
gemstore  --> S is capital

Comment: edited now, problem still the same. This was a typo error, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

module name should have capital 'S'
Replace `var app = angular.module('gemstore', ['qrScanner', 'ngRoute']);` with `var app = angular.module('gemStore', ['qrScanner', 'ngRoute']);`

One more thing, you don't need to wrap you module into the auto call function `(function(){}());`

Comment: I think i must say thx just for a response, but by adding the same response as other member in this forum the problem will not be fixed. Thank you!

Comment: I did not see response else I would not post.

Comment: `sorry = 1; if sorry < 1000 sorry ++`. Thanks